# maximizing the angle between a circle radius and a segment to another point

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a circle with radius $R$ and a point $P$ that is distance $r < R$ from the circle origin $O$. How could I find the maximum angle $\theta$ formed by $P$, $O$ and some other point on the circle?

[image]

I should be able to calculate this but somehow I'm having a brain cramp. It's at least $\sin^{-1} \frac{r}{R}$ (in the case where the angle at $P$ is a right angle) but I'm not sure if $\theta$ can be larger.

Comment: "How could I find the maximum angle θθ formed by PP, OO and some other point on the circle?" that other point on the circle is fixed?!

Comment: no, the point on the circle is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh -- it is exactly $\sin^{-1} \frac{r}{R}$ since by the Law of Sines, if the angle at $P$ is $\alpha$, then

$$\frac{\sin \theta}{r} = \frac{\sin \alpha}{R}$$

and

$$\sin \theta = \frac{r}{R} \sin \alpha$$

which is clearly maximized when $\sin \alpha = 1$.

Comment: No, $P$ lies on the circle having $OX$ as a diameter where $X$ is a point on the circle that makes $\alpha = \pi/2$.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstood your argument.

Answer (score 1):

Given two distinct points $A,B$ in the plane, the locus of points $P$ such that $\widehat{APB}$ equals a fixed angle $\theta$ is given by the union of two arcs of a circle. It follows that in order to solve your problem you just have to find a circle through $O$ and $P$ that is tangent to the initial circle.

Can you solve that? If not, please tell me, I will expand this answer.
Hint: the optimal points are given by the intersections of the original circle with the line through $P$ that is perpendicular to $OP$, hence the maximum angle is $\color{green}{\arcsin\frac{r}{R}}$.

[image]